# how do you write a list that ends with "or" instead of "and"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

How would I write the following sentence:

He could choose the red flag, the blue flag, or the green flag.

or is it?

He could choose the red flag, or the blue flag, or the green flag.

Since lists normally end with "and" I am confused if you need the clarity of an or after every comma.

Comment: He could choose the red, blue or green flag.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerating through a list can get very wordy.

He could choose the red flag or he could choose the green flag or he could choose the blue flag.

Both of your lists are correct but commas help keep the word count down.

I'm not familiar with any requirement of "and" in a list versus "or".